# Find summary statistics for a python dictionary with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose I have a dictionary:

```
a_dic = {'file1':["a","b","c"],
    'file2':["b","c","d"],
    'file3':["c","d","e"]}
```

I want to write a function to be able to return a dictionary/dataframe to find the occurrence of the keys like:

```
occurrence = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':2,'e':1}
```

Comment: Is your code not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `collections.Counter` object and `itertools.chain.from_iterable` function:

```
import collections, itertools

a_dic = {'file1':["a","b","c"], 'file2':["b","c","d"], 'file3':["c","d","e"]}
result = dict(collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a_dic.values())))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'c': 3, 'e': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
flat_list = [item for sublist in (a_dic.values()) for item in sublist]
print(Counter(flat_list))
```

Output

```
Counter({'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 2, 'a': 1, 'e': 1})
```